# Update list of dictionary from another list of dictionary python

Tags: python

```
list1 = [
    {"code": 1, "a": 7, "b": 9, "c": 24},
    {"code": 2, "a": 78, "b": 12, "c": 45},
    {"code": 3, "a": 3, "b": 5, "c": 16}
]
list2=[
    {"code": 1, "a": 45, "b": 21, "c": 24},
    {"code": 2, "a": 84, "b": 7, "c": 55}
]
```

Output:

```
list1 = [
    {"code": 1, "a": 45, "b": 21, "c": 24},
    {"code": 2, "a": 84, "b": 7, "c": 55},
    {"code": 3, "a": 3, "b": 5, "c": 16}
]
```

I need to update `list1` based on `list2` with the same key `"code"`.
I tried:

```
update_mapping = {k["code"]: k for k in list2}
list1 = [update_mapping.get(k["code"], k) for k in list1]
```

but it did not work.

Comment: "But it won't work" does not constitute a valid problem statement.

Comment: Can you use a different data structure?

Comment: `k["Case"]` seems to be a pretty clear typo

Comment: Maybe they shouldn't be lists. `codedict1 = {1: {'a': 7, 'b': 9, 'c': 24}, 2: {'a': 78, 'b': 12, 'c': 45}, 3: {'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 16}}` and `codedict2 = {1: {'a': 45, 'b': 21, 'c': 24}, 2: {'a': 84, 'b': 7, 'c': 55}}` would be easier to handle.

Comment: @Joffan dict of dict is a good idea. I will try it and let you know what happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any lookup problem, dictionaries are your friend. Transform your list into something keyed by code:

```
d1 = {d['code']: d for d in list1}
d2 = {d['code']: d for d in list2}
d1.update(d2)
list1 = list(d1.values())
```

Dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.6+, and `update` preserves key order, so this would work perfectly. For prior versions, use `collections.OrderedDict` (which is still available in Python 3.6+):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = OrderedDict((d['code'], d) for d in list1)
d2 = OrderedDict((d['code'], d) for d in list2)
d1.update(d2)
list1 = list(d1.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your lists are in correct order, another solution is to simply iterate over each item in the list1 and update it with the corresponding item in list2:

```
for item_1, item_2 in zip(list1, list2):
    item_1.update(item_2)
```

Also bear in mind the point "Mad" said about insertion order in dictionaries for python 3.6-

Comment: Any missing element will invalidate your method